# SQL Query for Calculating Trade Profits

Tags: sql, postgresql, algorithmic-trading, ticker, backtrader

**Trying to build a SQL script to calculate profit/loss percent per trade**

**Below is the original table**

```
SELECT id, exchange, ticker, signal, time, price 
from trade_data 
ORDER BY exchange, ticker, time;
```

| id | exchange | ticker | signal | time | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | BSE_DLY | UDAICEMENT | long | 2021-08-05 22:00:43.800603 | 46.4 |
| 27 | BSE_DLY | UDAICEMENT | close | 2021-08-06 10:00:26.718044 | 47.1 |
| 24 | NAS | TATAMOTORS | long | 2021-08-06 05:45:16.384777 | 300.85 |
| 22 | NAS | UDAICEMENT | long | 2021-08-06 05:00:25.23066 | 47.75 |
| 4 | NSE | NATIONALUM | long | 2021-08-05 22:00:43.996958 | 94.8 |
| 26 | NSE | NATIONALUM | close | 2021-08-06 09:45:17.511157 | 93.65 |
| 2 | NSE | NMDC | close | 2021-08-05 22:00:43.600858 | 178.05 |
| 14 | NSE | NMDC | long | 2021-08-06 03:45:11.243861 | 179.45 |
| 5 | NSE | SAIL | long | 2021-08-05 22:00:44.197164 | 140.4 |
| 25 | NSE | SAIL | close | 2021-08-06 09:45:17.441593 | 140.5 |
| 1 | NSE | TATACONSUM | close | 2021-08-05 21:57:56.840043 | 761 |
| 13 | NSE | TATACONSUM | long | 2021-08-06 03:37:38.371882 | 773 |
| 15 | NSE | TATAMOTORS | long | 2021-08-06 03:45:12.891371 | 300.65 |

**Formula for calculating profit/loss percent**

```
profit % =   (close_price-entry_price)   *  100
            ---------------------------
                 entry_price
```

> Print profit as 0 if Trade Entry is not available

The resulting dataset should look like below

| id | exchange | ticker | signal | time | price | profit % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | BSE_DLY | UDAICEMENT | long | 2021-08-05 22:00:43.800603 | 46.4 |  |
| 27 | BSE_DLY | UDAICEMENT | close | 2021-08-06 10:00:26.718044 | 47.1 | 1.5 |
| 24 | NAS | TATAMOTORS | long | 2021-08-06 05:45:16.384777 | 300.85 |  |
| 22 | NAS | UDAICEMENT | long | 2021-08-06 05:00:25.23066 | 47.75 |  |
| 4 | NSE | NATIONALUM | long | 2021-08-05 22:00:43.996958 | 94.8 |  |
| 26 | NSE | NATIONALUM | close | 2021-08-06 09:45:17.511157 | 93.65 | -1.21 |
| 2 | NSE | NMDC | close | 2021-08-05 22:00:43.600858 | 178.05 | 0 |
| 14 | NSE | NMDC | long | 2021-08-06 03:45:11.243861 | 179.45 |  |
| 5 | NSE | SAIL | long | 2021-08-05 22:00:44.197164 | 140.4 |  |
| 25 | NSE | SAIL | close | 2021-08-06 09:45:17.441593 | 140.5 | 0.07 |
| 1 | NSE | TATACONSUM | close | 2021-08-05 21:57:56.840043 | 761 | 0 |
| 13 | NSE | TATACONSUM | long | 2021-08-06 03:37:38.371882 | 773 |  |
| 15 | NSE | TATAMOTORS | long | 2021-08-06 03:45:12.891371 | 300.65 |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could use the LAG function to achieve this.
Idea would be to check the previous signal for specific exchange/ticker combination.
If current signal is equal to 'close' and there is no previous record (I guess that would be signal = 'long') then we put 0 and if there is previous record then we do the math. And for signal = 'long' we do nothing.

Please check if this is acceptable.

```
select id, exchange, ticker, signal, time, price,
    case 
        when signal = 'close' and prev_signal is null then 0 
        when signal = 'close' then round(((price-prev_price)*100)/price, 2)
    end as profit
from (
    select id, exchange, ticker, signal, time, price, 
        lag(signal) OVER (PARTITION BY exchange, ticker ORDER BY time) as prev_signal,
        lag(price) OVER (PARTITION BY exchange, ticker ORDER BY time) as prev_price
    from trade_Data
) as t0
```